# Gorm not updating array of child struct

Tags: go, go-gorm, cascade

I have the following structs

```
type Parent struct {
  ID       uuid     `gorm:"type:uuid" example:"070942aa-604f-42d2-bc6f-7295eae1929d"`
  Name     string
  Children []*Child `gorm:"constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE"`

}
type Child struct {
   ID       uuid     `gorm:"type:uuid" example:"070942aa-604f-42d2-bc6f-7295eae1929d"`
   Age      int
}
```

and I want to update the parent entity, with updated information of the child/children. As an example, update the children ages through saving/updating the parent entity, I am using this :

```
gorm.Updates(&updatedParent)
```

With &updatedParent containing the updated information of the children.
But **I can update the parent fields** (in this case Name), but **I can't update the child entities** (in this case age). Am I doing something wrong? I thought this gorm:"constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE" should be sufficient

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to update associations data, you have to specify this explicitly like:

```
DB.Session(&gorm.Session{FullSaveAssociations: true}).Updates(&parent)
```

See: https://gorm.io/docs/associations.html